# addObserver forkeypath not working in MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using the following code to know the **currentplayback** time. But it is not working when I play the song using the `MPMusicPlayerController`.Help me on this. Any ideas or suggestions could be very grateful

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime" options:0 context:nil];
```

Song Play code

```
MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:song]];
[musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];

[musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:song];
//[self.musicPlayer setVolume:volumeSlider.value];
[musicPlayer play];
```

Comment: possibly currentPlaybackTime is not updated using KVO methods, thus no observing is done.

Comment: I too have doubt dude I couldn't find any documentation related to it

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Volker, that property is not KVO compliant. See the docs here for the nsnotification events to listen for. Also make sure you call

```
[musicplayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications]
```

and

```
[musicplayer endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications]
```

For reference these are the notifications that get posted by the mpmusicplayercontroller:

```
MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMusicPlayerController/beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications